# Debugging simple Gradle Java App in Intellij

Tags: debugging, intellij-idea, gradle, gradlew

I'm trying to debug a simple gradle Java app in IntelliJ and I'm having the hardest time. I can run my tasks from the JetGradle plugin just fine, but when I right click the task and try to debug it, I get a message in the console that says it's connected, and then it says the equivalent disconnected:

```
Disconnected from the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:59303', transport: 'socket'
```

Not really sure how to proceed from here. I've tried looking online etc and haven't really found much except people talking about how JetGradle plugin isn't very good.

Here is my build.gradle if it matters.

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'idea'

task(parse, dependsOn: 'classes', type: JavaExec) {
    main = 'com.test.creator.Main'
    classpath = sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.4'
    compile 'org.xerial:sqlite-jdbc:3.7.2'
    compile 'net.sourceforge.jexcelapi:jxl:2.6.12'
}
```

Any help or direction would be appreciated.

#### A few additional things to note:

- I'm using the gradle Daemon as it dramatically decreased my build time with certain projects, so I'd prefer to keep that on.
- I'm using the Gradle Wrapper.
- I'm running IntelliJ 12.1.6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if right-clicking the Gradle task and hitting Debug is the right solution (you might be debugging Gradle here, rather than your application). The easiest solution is to just run/debug the `com.test.creator.Main` class directly (from IntelliJ).

PS: Gradle support is *much* better in IntelliJ 13 (EAP).

Comment: Good thinking. Your solution does work. I guess I thought I had to run it with gradle in order for gradles dependency management to work. I'll wait for a few days to see if there is a solution, but thank you very much for this in the mean time.